# How to group remote GIT repositories

Tags: git

I used to have a setup where I somehow grouped 3 of the remote repositories (for convenience) that I used to push the changes to all 3 remotes at once. How can I achieve this again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could accomplish this by adding multiple remotes [such as in this SO post: [pull/push from multiple remote locations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/849308/pull-push-from-multiple-remote-locations) ], then either using a git commit/push/pull alias that pushes to all three of your remote repos, or via [git hooks](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks).